# Expand the function in a Maclaurin series $\ln(5\cos^{3}(x))$

Tags: taylor-expansion

$$\ln(5\cos^{3}(x))$$ Need to be expanded: $x^{4}$

I need to end this problem.
So I laid the beginning of the function.
$$\cos x=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^4}{4!}+o(x^4)$$
$$5\cos^3(x)=5\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+o(x^4)\right)^3=5-\frac{15x^2}{2!}+\frac{35}{8}x^4+o(x^4).$$

I do not know what to do next.

Comment: Note you can use $\log$ rules to simplify the problem considerably.

Comment: @GFauxPas, Show it, please practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be cute about it, note that $\cos x = \sqrt{1 - \sin^2 x}$, so
$$
\ln(5\cos^3 x)=\ln 5 + 3\ln\cos x=\ln 5 + \frac{3}{2}\ln(1-\sin^2 x)=\ln 5 - \frac{3}{2}\sin^2 x - \frac{3}{4}\sin^4 x + O(x^6).
$$
To get the $x^4$ term, you just need $\sin^2 x \approx (x - x^3/6)^2 \approx x^2 - x^4/3$, so
$$
\ln(5\cos^3 x)\approx \ln 5 - \frac{3}{2}\left(x^2-\frac{1}{3}x^4\right)-\frac{3}{4}x^4=\ln 5 - \frac{3}{2}x^2 - \frac{1}{4}x^4.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Since 
$$\cos x = \prod_{n\geq 0}\left(1-\frac{4x^2}{(2n+1)^2 \pi^2}\right)$$
we have:
$$\log \cos x = -\sum_{n \geq 0}\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{4^m x^{2m}}{m(2n+1)^{2m}\pi^{2m}}=-\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(4^m-1)\,\zeta(2m)\,x^{2m}}{m\pi^{2m}}$$
so, in a neighbourhood of $x=0$:
$$\log(5\cos^3 x) = \log 5-3\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(4^m-1)\,\zeta(2m)\,x^{2m}}{m\pi^{2m}}=\log 5-\frac{3}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{4}x^4+O(x^6).$$